# How to avoid echo in webrtc?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, web-audio-api

I need to implement simple peer to peer video calling app.

I use the [next simple example](https://github.com/fireship-io/webrtc-firebase-demo).

When I run it locally and open web page on my MacBook / iPhone it has echo. I hear what I just told. Even before starting a call.

I record audio and quality is terrible:

```
const chunks = [];
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false }).then(handleSuccess);
const handleSuccess = function (stream) {
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (event) => {
        chunks.push(event.data);
        sendData(event.data);
    });
};
```

I tried the next code but it did not help:

```
const pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
pc.setConfiguration({echoCancellation: true});
pc.setConfiguration({noiseSuppression: true, autoGainControl: true});
```

How to remove echo? Should I use separate lib for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular sample example attaches the local camera to an unmuted video element which plays the sound locally and creates echo. Adding a "muted" attribute [to it](https://github.com/fireship-io/webrtc-firebase-demo/blob/main/index.html#L14) should fix this.

Comment: I solved my issue. Is there any practical reason to have a video tag without "muted" in peer to peer video chat app?

Comment: For the local video no. For the remute it depends on whether you prefer a single video element or separate audio/video elements.